# SQLite check for two decimals at most

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a price column and the task is to write a check clause which verifies that any inserted price has two decimals at most. My idea is to store the price as TEXT.
I turned google upside down but couldn't find a reply.

Thank you for considering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about taking advantage of SQLite3's fluid type system, i.e. treating number as a string:

```
check(instr(price, '.') = 0 or (length(price) - instr(price, '.') <= 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not store numeric values as strings.
Use the data type `REAL` for the column and this `CHECK` constraint:

```
CHECK (CAST(price * 100 AS INTEGER) / 100.0 = price)
```